# Luntbuild No modules defined! Error

Tags: java, build, continuous-integration, luntbuild

I am trying to set up Luntbuild 1.6.2 from scratch in our UAT environment. I have created a project, builder and schedule. We use subversion as source control so i have specified the repository and path as well in luntbuild.

But when I trigger the schedule nothing happens and system log reads as below:

```
com.luntsys.luntbuild.utility.ValidationException: No modules defined! 
 at com.luntsys.luntbuild.vcs.Vcs.validateModules(Vcs.java:323) 
 at com.luntsys.luntbuild.vcs.SvnAdaptor.validateModules(SvnAdaptor.java:739) 
 at com.luntsys.luntbuild.vcs.Vcs.validate(Vcs.java:342) 
 at com.luntsys.luntbuild.db.Project.validate(Project.java:347) 
 at com.luntsys.luntbuild.db.Project.validateAtBuildTime(Project.java:363) 
 at com.luntsys.luntbuild.db.Schedule.validateAtBuildTime(Schedule.java:383) 
 at com.luntsys.luntbuild.BuildGenerator.execute(BuildGenerator.java:186) 
 at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202) 
 at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:529)
```

I don't know what I am missing? any clues...??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this problem with help of one of my colleague...

You have to add the module inside VCS adapter tab and you need not to define all entries. I left all of it as blank and it resolved the issue.